# Ajax posting null data

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to echo a php variable from an Ajax request but the data is being returned as "null" and im not sure why. Here is my post request:

```
    jQuery.ajax({
        url:'/api/registerLoginViaFacebook.php',
        data: {'test1':'test1','test2':'test2'},
        type:'POST',
        success: function(result) {
            jQuery('header').html(result);
        }
    })
```

The data i'm posting here is just test data. As i'm having the same problem posting the real data. Here is the `registerLoginViaFacebook.php` file:

```
<?php

   echo "<p>hey</p>";
   echo "<p>".json_encode($data)."</p>";

?>
```

the html thats getting inserted in the `<header>` is

hey

null

suggesting that the data i specified was never sent - at least that's what I make of it. I tried including `$_REQUEST['data'];` at the start of the file as per some suggestions I found on here but still no joy. Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: What is populating `$data`? Just for grins set `$data = 'foo';` in your PHP script and run again.

Comment: Have you watched the AJAX request / response in the browser's developer tools? Have you included the jQuery library in the project? Are there any errors reported? Are you running this on a web-server?

Comment: `$data` isn't being initialised in your PHP code. Try to echo `$_POST['test1']` or `$_POST['test2']`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [receive json post with php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18866571/receive-json-post-with-php)

Comment: I thought you had to use a variable in the post?  `data:{test1:'test1', test2:'test2'}`

Comment: Do yourself a favor, simply place a `print_r($_POST)` or `var_dump($_POST)` in the PHP page which receives the form submission. Fill out your form, submit and look closely at the data printed to the screen. Familiarize yourself with how form data is posted to scripts, including what gets passed and what doesn't.

Comment: Php requires an extra step to read json value. Take a look at referenced article

Comment: Hey Jay print_r revealed what I wanted! i think setting $data= $_POST would be the correct answer if you wanted to post that mate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set `$data` in  your PHP script. Since you are sending the information via POST you can do this:

```
$data = $_POST;
```

Answer (score 0):

On the PHP end, try using `$_POST['test1']` and `$_POST['test2']`. This should contain the data you sent via jQuery.